# How to log all my DNS queries?

Tags: logs, dns

How can I create logs of every DNS query that my computer makes along with the responses it gets?

Answer (score 21):

You can have `tcpdump` log all port 53 UDP and TCP activity.

Comment: Any details on how?

Comment: This is the best answer as we can't be sure the OP (or other readers) have access to the DNS server - only their local machine. To answer @e-sushi's question take a tcpdump using the utility (check out the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/tcpdump) or a [good primer with examples](https://danielmiessler.com/study/tcpdump/#gs.0fNZozw)). Your best bet is to dump to a file and then pull that data into [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) for review & analysis.

Comment: https://github.com/gamelinux/passivedns/ seems to be doing just that, see `./doc/How-it-works.txt`

Comment: `tcpdump udp port 53`

Comment: It may not select the outbound network interface by default, so you need a bit more: `tcpdump --list-interfaces`, `tcpdump udp port 53 --interface (pickone)`.  Also consider verbosity: `-vv`

Answer (score 13):

To show and save to file all the `A` DNS requests, run this:

```
script -q -c "sudo tcpdump -l port 53 2>/dev/null | grep --line-buffered ' A? ' | cut -d' ' -f8" | tee dns.log
```

Example output:

> google.com.
> wikipedia.org.

**UPDATE (2023)**:
output format of `tcpdump` changed; domain name is in field #9, not #8.

Fixed one-liner:

```
script -q -c "sudo tcpdump -l port 53 2>/dev/null | grep --line-buffered ' A? ' | cut -d' ' -f9" | tee dns.log
```

Comment: This command worked for me, but I don't understand why `script` is needed. Could you explain?

Comment: Will print responses with implicit request info on a single line: `sudo tcpdump -vvli eth0 port 53 | grep --line-buffered " q: A? " | cut -d' ' -f16-`

Comment: This just prints out a bunch of lines that say `A?`

Comment: @Herohtar the output format of tcpdump has been changed. Now domain name is in field #9, not #8. Try `script -q -c "sudo tcpdump -l port 53 2>/dev/null | grep --line-buffered ' A? ' | cut -d' ' -f9" | tee dns.log`

Answer (score 11):

The easiest way is to install Bind locally. Most distros default install of Bind will be non-autoritative caching-only.

Simply add a `logging {}` config block (as described in the [Bind 9 Configuration Reference](http://www.bind9.net/manual/bind/9.3.1/Bv9ARM.ch06.html#AEN1573)) then set your system to use `127.0.0.1` or `::1` as the DNS resolver.

Comment: Given how large bind is and its lackluster security record, I think many people would hesitate to install something like that for the sole purpose of logging.

Comment: doesn't bind have the issue that the nameservers in /etc/resolv.conf are not used but nameservers must be listed explicitly in the bind config?

Comment: No. `/etc/resolv.conf` is the system resolver list. Bind's default configuration is to look up the authoritative name servers and ask them. You *could* forward all requests to a specific server (or set, such as your ISP, OpenDNS or Google Public DNS) but it's not required to do so in the config. I do this all the time. I can't even count the number of times I've set up caching only name servers.

Answer (score 6):

[dnsmasq](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/doc.html) is far easier to configure as a DNS aggregator/caching daemon than BIND, and for that purpose, the performance might just be better.  If you turn logging up to "debug", all the questions and answers show up in whatever `syslog` has configured for debug messages.

Dnsmasq also makes it easy to get rid of abusive advertisers and dirtbag privacy invading "analytic" creeps by aliasing entire domains to 127.0.0.1

Comment: See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/728192/dnsmasq-is-not-logging-queries

Answer (score 2):

One easy way to filter the DNS , for the requests you are interested in is to 
grep the next row too `grep -A 2` where -A is after and 2 rows after . If the server has a lot of DNS requests increase from 2 to 4-5

```
tcpdump -l port 53 |grep -A 2  redis
```

the second line will be the answer from DNS -> IP, CNAME ,none , other

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly Snort can selectively monitor traffic based on user defined rules. However, Snort will not create logs for DNS requests when your computer, i.e. its resolver, can answer the question from its cache.

Answer (score 0):

Please try [PassiveDNS](https://github.com/gamelinux/passivedns) - A tool to collect DNS records passively to aid Incident handling, Network
Security Monitoring (NSM) and general digital forensics.

To make it simple to use, I created a docker image called [vimagick/passivedns](https://hub.docker.com/r/vimagick/passivedns)

```yaml
version: "3.8"
services:
  passivedns:
    image: vimagick/passivedns
    command: >
      -d "||"
      -i eth0
      -l /var/log/passivedns/passivedns.log
      -L /var/log/passivedns/passivedns-nx.log
      -p /var/run/passivedns.pid
      -P 86400
      -S 256
      -X 46CDNOPRSTMnx
    volumes:
      - ./data:/var/log/passivedns
    network_mode: host
    privileged: true
    restart: unless-stopped
```

Up and running:

```bash
# assume your iface name is eth0
$ ifconfig eth0

$ mkdir passivedns
$ cd passivedns

# paste yaml content here
$ vim docker-compose.yml

$ docker compose up -d

$ tail -f data/passivedns.log
```

Example output:

```
#timestamp||dns-client ||dns-server||RR class||Query||Query Type||Answer||TTL||Count
1322849924.408856||10.1.1.1||8.8.8.8||IN||upload.youtube.com.||A||74.125.43.117||46587||5
1322849924.408857||10.1.1.1||8.8.8.8||IN||upload.youtube.com.||A||74.125.43.116||420509||5
1322849924.408858||10.1.1.1||8.8.8.8||IN||www.adobe.com.||CNAME||www.wip4.adobe.com.||43200||8
1322849924.408859||10.1.1.1||8.8.8.8||IN||www.adobe.com.||A||193.104.215.61||43200||8
1322849924.408860||10.1.1.1||8.8.8.8||IN||i1.ytimg.com.||CNAME||ytimg.l.google.com.||43200||3
1322849924.408861||10.1.1.1||8.8.8.8||IN||clients1.google.com.||A||173.194.32.3||43200||2
```