# dnsmasq is not logging queries?

Tags: logs, dnsmasq

I need to provide a split DNS capability for around 8 records, so am running a Ubuntu 20.04 container with dnsmasq 2.80 from repo. This provides the required forward and reverse lookup capabilities, however I need to be able to log all queries to identify any missing / additional records which should be added.

Out of the box, dnsmasq sends events to syslog which are being recorded in /var/log/syslog.

I added `log-queries=extra` to the configuration file, but the queries do not appear in /var/log/syslog.

I switched to using a dedicated log file (`log-facility=/var/log/dnsmasq/dnsmasq.log`). Again the start up messages are logged as expected, but no query logs.

How can I see the queries the server is handling? (must be non-interactive)

Answer (score 0):

`log-queries` (without the `=extra`) in the configuration file worked for me.